# Bash Terminal keeps showing "No such file or directory" at startup

Tags: bash, terminal

> -bash: /Users/MarksMac/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate: No
>   such file or directory

Basically, how do i remove the above error? I am using a mac 10.9.1
I have tried looking up for answers but i still can't solve this. Although it's very simple. Sorry, I'm new to terminal.

Comment: `activate` is needed to initiate the shell's environment. It seems like some sort of virtual environment wants to be invoked. More details are probably to be found in `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_rc`

Answer (score 2):

Check the contents of your **~/.bash_profile**, or **~/.bashrc**, for anything regarding this.

You can try renaming all three files to something else, then relaunch Terminal. If the problem goes away, put each file back one by one and test each time to find which file contains the 'bad' line.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `.enstaller4rc` under your home directory. Then reopen the terminal. That error would be gone.